# How can I express sentences like "How long is ..." or "How old is ... " or "How convenient is ..." etc.?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, phrase-requests, questions

I want to know if there's a grammar structure that can be used when you want to know the **extent** of an adjective. E.g.

> 会長は若いね　＞＞　How young is he?
>
> この映画はとっても長いよ！　＞＞　How long is it?
>
> たきくんは遅れてしまいました。　＞＞　How late was he?

I know that there are other ways you can ask these questions (会長は何歳ですか？・映画はどのくらいかかりますか？・たきくんは何時に来ましたか？) but I want to know if there's a structure like "How [adjective] is [noun]?" in English that can be used for any adjective.

Comment: どのくらい springs to mind, but I don't feel confident enough to give a full answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can say "どのくらい?" (casual) or "どのくらいですか?" (polite). You do not even need to repeat the adjective.

> 「この映画はとっても長いよ！」「どのくらい？」
>
> 「たきくんは遅れてしまいました。」「どのくらいですか？」

(If 会長は若いね was said referring to the appearance of 会長 ("He *looks* young, doesn't he?"), asking how young he *looks* is strange. If the first speaker seems to know the exact age and said 「会長はとても若いんですよ」, it's fine to say 「どのくらいですか？」)

Comment: I see! Can I include the adjective in the sentence, though? Imagine my friend has invited me to see a film (without saying anything about it,) can I ask どのくらい長いですか？ Or if I want to know about how fast the bullet train goes, could I say 新幹線はどのくらい速いですか？etc.

Comment: For い　adjectives there is a cnominalizing conjugation with い→さ　that makes it into a noun describing the extent:
高さ　height
良さ　goodness
速さ　fastness. These might help be more specific about the quality you are describing. Not sure if something similar is necessary for な adj